# Can I setup an android sdk package offline?

Tags: android, android-studio

I had a problem in my internet connection while downloading or updating a large sized package on android sdk manager as it always failed.

I downloaded this package alone from its link ( https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-25_r06.zip ).

So how can I setup this by new android studio sdk manager ?

Comment: Did you try put files from zip to folder `path_to_sdk/system-images/android-25/google_apis/x86/` ?

Comment: You mean I replace the contents of this folder by the files from the new zip file ? No I didn't try this.